# Convert Multiple Columns from String to Float and Int

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert multiple columns in my df from string to int and float. I used fillna method to get rid of NaN values however I'm still getting an error. Here's what I did:

```
df = [['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4']]

df = df[['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4']].fillna(0)
convert_dict = {'column1': int,
                 'column2': float,
                  'column3': int, 
                    'column4': float}
df = df.astype(convert_dict)
```

The error says `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`

Edit: Removed `inplace=True`

Comment: You have np.nan in the column you want to convert to int

Comment: `df = [[...]].fillna(0, inplace=True)` doesn't make sense. I'm assuming you are missing a `df` in there and you don't need `inplace` if you are assigning the result to `df`.

Comment: @BEN_YO yes. Does np.nan works with fillna?

Comment: You generally don't use `inplace=True` and also assign the dataframe to a variable, can you confirm your input and output and provide a [mcve]?

Comment: As Ben points out, you cannot convert nan to int, you should `fillna` or keep it as float

Comment: @RichieV I used ```fillna``` method and assign ```(0)``` but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @AChampion I removed ```inplace=True``` but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: should you be using `df = df[['column1'...` instead of `df = [['column1'...` ?

Comment: @RichieV Got it. Thanks

Comment: `df = df.astype(convert_dict, errors = 'ignore')` should work.

Comment: is this solved?

Comment: @RichieV Yep, all good. Thank you!

Comment: @r0ot293 your suggestion worked too. Thanks, guys. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Int64`, which supports missing integer values:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, None, 4], 
                   'B': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, None]})

convert_dict = {'A': 'Int64', 'B': float}
convert_dict

for field, new_type in convert_dict.items():
    df[field] = df[field].astype(new_type)

print(df)
print(df.dtypes)

      A    B
0     1  1.0
1     2  2.0
2  <NA>  3.0
3     4  NaN

A      Int64
B    float64
dtype: object
```